# Access HTTP on HTTPS page to get Cookie

Tags: javascript, php, http, https, cross-domain

I'm aware of the many hacks, I tried to google it, but I didn't really find anything I could use.

I have an IP camera with some pretty dumb authentication system, which supports only HTTP.

I need to show image from this camera on a HTTPS page, but the camera won't show anything until it's been "logged in", which sets a cookie for the camera IP.

I tried to open the login page (HTTP) with ajax, but chrome blocked it

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://control_page_ip' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran
insecure content from 'http://camera_ip:8881/login.cgi?login_info':
this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

All I need is to once access that http page and get the cookie.
Image will load fine over http - with a warning, but it will load.

How to do this - the easiest way? Ideally without any server-side helper stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Omg I've invented the stupidest hack on earth, and it worked! I've fooled chrome into thinking the login page is an image :D

```
<img style="display:none" src="http://camera_ip:8881/login.cgi?login_info">
```

And it works fine - sets the cookie :)